# Is there a name for class methods which replace 'def'?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Here's something I've done a lot. I'd like to know the name for it, if a name exists:

```
class C
  include MyCustomDef  # i wrote this somewhere else
  my_custom_def :foo do |x|
    2*x
  end
  # foo and bar do the exact same thing
  def bar x
    puts 'called a method!'
    2*x
  end
end
```

That is, I create a custom method definer to use instead of plain `def`, which wraps some behavior or other, along with a `define_method` on the block passed in.

For example, I recently used this to define methods so that their values would be cached in the object, and another method `to_hash` would automatically be defined and return a hash of `method_name=>method_value`.

I'd like to know a name for this pattern, if a name exists. Possibly, it's  a subset of a family of metaprogramming techniques, and only the family has a name. Either way, I'd like to know what you'd call it.

Answer (score 1):

Methods such as Ruby's `attr_*`, ActiveRecord's `belongs_to`/`has_many` or Rails's `acts_as_*` are sometimes (wrongly) called *macros*, but they really aren't. AFAIK, there is no common name for such methods.

The general technique is called *code synthesis*, which is similar to *code generation* (like Rails's generators), but without actually generating the code; the code is ephemeral. However, code synthesis is not exclusive to methods, e.g. `Struct.new` synthesizes classes.